# ts-node throws ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND for simple import './hi'

Tags: node.js, typescript, ts-node

I created a project for illustration:

https://github.com/Ser5/ts-node-nohi

You can test it with

```bash
git clone https://github.com/Ser5/ts-node-nohi
cd ts-node-nohi
npm i
npx ts-node main.ts
```

It throws this error:

```
G:\Programming\JS\ts-node-nohi\node_modules\ts-node\dist-raw\node-internal-modules-esm-resolve.js:366
    throw new ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND(
          ^
CustomError: Cannot find module 'G:\Programming\JS\ts-node-nohi\hi' imported from G:\Programming\JS\ts-node-nohi\main.ts
    at finalizeResolution (G:\Programming\JS\ts-node-nohi\node_modules\ts-node\dist-raw\node-internal-modules-esm-resolve.js:366:11)
    at moduleResolve (G:\Programming\JS\ts-node-nohi\node_modules\ts-node\dist-raw\node-internal-modules-esm-resolve.js:801:10)
    at Object.defaultResolve (G:\Programming\JS\ts-node-nohi\node_modules\ts-node\dist-raw\node-internal-modules-esm-resolve.js:912:11)
    at G:\Programming\JS\ts-node-nohi\node_modules\ts-node\src\esm.ts:218:35
    at entrypointFallback (G:\Programming\JS\ts-node-nohi\node_modules\ts-node\src\esm.ts:168:34)
    at G:\Programming\JS\ts-node-nohi\node_modules\ts-node\src\esm.ts:217:14
    at addShortCircuitFlag (G:\Programming\JS\ts-node-nohi\node_modules\ts-node\src\esm.ts:409:21)
    at resolve (G:\Programming\JS\ts-node-nohi\node_modules\ts-node\src\esm.ts:197:12)
    at resolve (G:\Programming\JS\ts-node-nohi\node_modules\ts-node\src\child\child-loader.ts:15:39)
    at nextResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:173:28)
```

While `tsc main.ts` processes the files without problems. For example, the following commands produces the expected result:

```bash
tsc --outDir ../ts-node-yeshi/ main.ts && cd ../ts-node-yeshi/ && node main.js
```

How to convince `ts-node`, that my code is OK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some interesting behavior with Typescript and file extensions in imports. Read about it here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-7/#type-in-package-json-and-new-extensions

Short answer: Add a `.ts` file extension to your import in `main.ts`:

```js
import { hi } from './hi.ts';

hi();
```

Then things should work as expected.

Comment: Thanks! It's cumbersome, but it works. I also read this section: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-5-0/#moduleresolution-bundler , it says that we should be able to import modules without extensions, however I'm not able to get it working. Thus I use your advice for adding 'ts' extension. VSCode complains about the import with the extension, so I suppressed the complaint with //@ts-ignore. It also is weird that I still can to import ts files from 'hi.ts' without 'ts' extension. Looks like ts-node requires 'ts' extensions only in top level file - i.e. main.ts.

Comment: UPDATE. No... actually, I can't use nested imports without 'ts'. As soon as I call the imported code - it still fails. Looks like I have to put 'ts' extensions in every import and pair each of them with //@ts-ignore. But it will greatly pollute the code, so it is barely an option, really.

Comment: @Ser5 try using `.js` instead. Maybe I should update my answer to use that.